# Get the dynamic Fiscal Year if I already have Fiscal Year Start and End Dates in my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to set the Fiscal Year to be dynamic so I won't change it every Fiscal Year Start.

I already have all dates I need in my calendar table as you can see in the picture.
Fiscal Year Start Date & Fiscal Year End Date (for all the years)
[image: Calendar Table]

I can't use `... WHERE FiscalYear = Year(GetDate())` as Jan of all years almost belongs to the previous calendar year ex: 01/01/2024 is still Fiscal Year 2023

I also can't use a case when expression as the start and end of each Fiscal Year is different.

How can I possibly get the dynamic Fiscal Year in my case?

Comment: Whats wrong with `DateValue >= FiscalYearStart AND DateValue <= FiscalYearEnd`?

Comment: @ThomA I never used the DateValue function in SQL. Can you please explain more?

Comment: It's not a function, it your *date value*.

Comment: yep, this's what I used  WHERE SYSDATETIME() BETWEEN [FiscalYearStart] AND [FiscalYearEnd], but I am still testing it as fiscal start and end dates are overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example data:

```
create table #FiscalYears
(
    FiscalYear int,
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date
)

insert into #FiscalYears values
(2023,'2023-01-29','2024-02-03'),
(2024,'2024-02-04','2025-02-01')
```

You can get the current Fiscal Year value as follows:

```
select FiscalYear 
from #FiscalYears
where getdate() >= StartDate
and getdate() <= EndDate
```

Currently this gives the result `2023`, but once it's 4th Feb 2024 or later (and on or before 1st Feb 2025), it will return `2024`.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer - if you found it helpful, please consider upvoting it as well.